# What does it mean to prove that two systems have to same theorems?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Lets say there is two systems $L_1$ and $L_2$.If I get asked:

> Show that $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same theorems.

Is it sufficient to prove the axioms of $L_1$ using the axioms of $L_2$ or vice-versa ? Or do I have to show that a wf is a theorem of $L_1$ iff it is a theorem of $L_2$ ?

Comment: You need to assume that the *rules* of both systems are the same, and they only differ in the axioms. If that is the case, you can prove that $L_1$ and $L_2$ have the same theorems *if and only if* the axioms of $L_2$ are theorems of $L_1$ and the axioms of $L_1$ are theorems of $L_2$. I see there are already answers that help you about that. However, if the rules are by any chance different, then this equivalence does not *necessarily*  follow. It would still follow, though, if you can prove that the rules in $L_2$ follow from the rules in $L_1$ and vice versa.

Comment: @StinkingBishop: thanks: I was debating whether to say anything about that.  I have added an aside to my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed sufficient to show that each axiom of $L_1$ is derivable from the axioms of $L_2$ and vice versa. This implies that any wff is a theorem of $L_1$ iff it a theorem of $L_2$.

To see why assume $\phi$ is a theorem of $L_1$. The proof $\Pi$ of $\phi$ can only use finitely many axioms of $L_1$, say $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$. If we have proofs $\Pi_1, \ldots, \Pi_k$  of $\alpha_1, \ldots, \alpha_k$ in $L_2$, we can combine $\Pi_1, \ldots, \Pi_k$ and $\Pi$ to give a proof of $\phi$ in $L_2$. So any theorem of $L_1$ is a theorem of $L_2$. Likewise, swapping $L_1$ and $L_2$ any theorem of $L_2$ is a theorem of $L_1$.

Aside: the above assumes that your systems have the same inference rules, e.g., if you are looking at a typical exposition of first-order logic, as a Hilbert style system with modus ponens as the only inference rule. If you are looking at systems with different inference rules (e.g, a natural deduction calculus on the one hand and a Hilbert-style system on the other), you will also have to show that each rule of $L_2$ is derivable (or more generally, what is called permissible) on the basis of the axioms and rules of $L_1$ and vice versa.